# Where to put off()?

Tags: jquery

I have a common.js file that I use and I have a ajax function for form submits but I'm not sure where to put the off() handler.  Would that go within the submit handler or outside of it?  I'm trying to avoid duplicate form submits.

This is what I have:

```
$(function () {
     $("body").on("submit", "form[data-ajaxform]", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         /* handle ajax post */
      });

 });
```

Comment: body doesnt have submit event form does. You should change body to corrct form selector

Comment: The reason I'm using the body selector is that some of my forms are from a $("#dynamicarea").load("/ajaxform.html");  So the form wouldn't be initially on the page.

Comment: You could add them to array or jquery selector upon loading or you could run this command upon every new form loads up `var forms = $('form')`

Comment: Good idea, I haven't thought of that before.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use off() directly after submit like below:

```
$(function () {
     $("body").on("form[data-ajaxform]", "submit", function (e) {
           /*submit should be in second param so it can be submitted*/
         e.preventDefault();
         /* handle ajax post */
       // use off here
         $(this).off("submit");//after submission of form this no more to be submitted
      });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I forgot you can chain events/function in Jquery.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work.  Don't you need the call within the event handler? Otherwise, it just sets the event handler and kills it before it has a chance for it to fire.

Comment: Form will still, submit this will only remove submit event from body tag which will remove the handler you yourself are attaching which only prevents bubbling up

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `one` instead of `on` to have an event handler that runs only once.

Comment: Yeah, that's also a way to use.